# testing network application on localhost

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, localhost

Well i have made a chat client where every user can connect to other user using IP address. I have to demonstrate the application, however, using localhost.

Now suppose i open 2 instances of the application and tell one of them the ip address of the other(which in this case is localhost) it will easily connect with the other instance and will work fine. However now if i open a third instance of the application and put it in the IP of localhost, out of first 2 instances with which it will connect, over a network it wouldn't be a problem because simply all the IP addresses would be unique but i have to give demo over localhost and i can't think of some way to link the 3rd application with any other of my choice.

Comment: Along with IP address, there must be a port as well, right ?

Comment: you can create IP aliases and have a single interface listen to multiple addresses. It's simple enough, though you can't use dhcp on the interface while doing so.

Comment: Could always setup virtual machines if you want to truly demonstrate multiple computers rather than "faking" it all on the same screen/operating system.

Comment: @Madhur Ohhh wow it just didn't strike me. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisSinclair A brilliant suggestion will discuss it with professor

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem completely but Loopback aliasing may help.
You can create multiple "logical" loopback interfaces and configure unique IP addresses to each of them.

In Solaris I can do something like this:

```
ifconfig lo0:1 plumb
ifconfig lo0:1 11.11.11.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

...
ifconfig lo0:99 plumb
ifconfig lo0:99 99.99.99.99 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Comment: i did tried network aliasing by changing my hosts file to point multiple id addresses to localhost. While the application do seem to recognize them the RemoteEndPoint still ended up recognize the one and only 127.0.0.1 behind the mask.